# SizeHint of animated area while dragging QDockWidget

Tags: qt, qwidget

I have QDockWidget that dynamically changes layout depending on area where it will be docked. While dockwidget docking, QMainWindow tries to animate area where widget will be docked, and sets width and height of animated area based on current sizeHint of docked widget. Is there is way in Qt to overload this behaviour(sizeHint of animated area)?

Comment: Does reimplementing of sizeHint() of docking widget is possible?

Comment: I use standart layouts(QVBoxLayout,QHBoxLayout), there is no problem in sizeHint, in docking widget it's correct; main problem -  docking widget does not know anything where QMainWindow animates docking area right now

Comment: Huh. Design of docking widgets implies that QMainWindow decides where and how to place a widget. I think that you should try to view QMainWindow sources for workaround. Something with mouse events.